# Finding the type of algebraic structure formed by the given types of set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let's say I am given a set that has a bunch of sets as its element, for instance, the power set of natural numbers less than or equal to 1, denoted as $P(1)$. Is it true that such kinds of sets, where the elements are sets, never form a group under a set operation? I am wondering what it means for sets to have inverses?

Comment: "I am wondering what it means for sets to have inverses?" - This depends on the group law, i.e., how you compose sets.

Comment: The symmetric difference makes it an Abelian group, moreover a vector space over the 2 element field.